# Ionic - Angularjs : $stateProvider couldn't get the nested views

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic to build a simple application , that consists of [index.html ]  , [home.html],[about.html] , [ cal.html -- has additional and subtraction.html ]

The application navigates very well . expect the nested views , when i click on addition or on  subtraction nothings happens !

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var app=angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);

app.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        if (cordova.platformId === "ios" && window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

            // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
            // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
            // a much nicer keyboard experience.
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
});




app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

      .state('home', {
          url: "/home",
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
      })

     .state('about', {
         url: "/about",
         templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
     })

     .state('calc', {
         url: "/calc",
         templateUrl: "templates/calc.html"
     })

        
      .state('calc.addition', {
          url: "/addition",
          templateUrl: "templates/addition.html"

     
      })

     .state('calc.subtraction', {
         url: "/subtraction",
         templateUrl: "templates/subtraction.html"
     })

   


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!--For users deploying their apps to Windows 8.1 or Android Gingerbread, platformOverrided.js
    will inject platform-specific code from the /merges folder -->
    <script src="js/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>

          <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
              <ion-nav-back-button>
              </ion-nav-back-button>
          </ion-nav-bar>

          <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Calculate.html

```html
<ion-view view-title="Calculator"> <!-- view-title  to show the name of the page in the bar -->
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
            This is Calculator  page
        </p>

        <a ui-sref ="calc.subtraction"> Addition</a>
        <a ui-sref="calc.subtraction"> Subtraction</a>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

addtion.html

```html
<ion-view view-title="Addition">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
            This is Addition page
        </p>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

subtraction.html

```html
<ion-view view-title="Subtraction">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
            This is Substraction  page
        </p>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Did you put `ui-view` in side the parent?

Comment: I guess you forgot to Add the ui-view directive inside of your parent view, which is Calculate.html

Answer (score 1):

There are severa things to take in account:

- You cannot put the ion-nav-view and ion-nav-bar from the index inside a ion-pane, ion-content, etc. they are designed to be children of the body tag.

  ```
  <body ng-app="starter">
      <!--
        The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
      -->
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <!--
    The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
    Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
    have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
  -->
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  ```
- Once you remove those you can keep your double header using a title inside ion-nav-bar and a sub-header on each view.
- Finally for the routing, you have to options:

  1. Use ionic ion-view to render a whole new view as you did (this will get the back arrow and another ionic features)
  2. Create those view without the ionic directives (ion-view, etc) to render them inside the Calculator content.

In this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/tinchomm/pen/mRdXoW) you can see that the substraction link uses the first option and the Addition link uses the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the view for `calc.html` to add an element for UI-Router to use to display the nested content, like so:

```
<ion-view view-title="Calculator" id="calcView">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <p>This is Calculator page</p>

    <a ui-sref="calc.subtraction">Addition</a>
    <a ui-sref="calc.subtraction">Subtraction</a>

    <!-- view container for addition/subtraction pages -->
    <div ui-view></div>
  </ion-content>
```

At this point, you should see the content for the subtraction & addition pages, but with one problem: the content in the calculator (parent) view is no longer visible. To fix that, you'll need to specify some CSS to position things correctly, like so:

```
<!-- this goes in the <head> element -->
<style>
#calcView > .scroll-content > .scroll {
  /* this forces the .scroll container to full-height, which 
  allows the nested content to be visible */
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#calcView [ui-view] .pane {
  /* this offsets the top of the addition/subtraction view, to push it downwards, 
  below the content/links that are in the calc.html template. You'll need to
  manually calculate/adjust this value as you develop your app's design. */
  top: 60px; 
}
</style>
```

There's a variety of ways to implement nested views, including naming them (which allows you to nest multiple, separate views in one pane), and more. Docs are a bit deep, but they're accurate: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#nested-states--views. I've learned a lot from Github/Gist examples, so I'd definitely recommend searching along those lines as well.

* Edit: [@Hiraqui is absolutely correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41453527/844976) about something I forgot to include in my answer: I had to shift your `<ion-nav-view`> element out of the `<ion-content>` element, so your `<body>` element now looks like this:

```
<body ng-app="starter">    
  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>    
      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-bar>
    </ion-content>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-pane>
</body>
```